# How to setup a Ubuntu Raid to be accessed by the Domain Active Directory Server

Tags: 12.04, raid, active-directory

I'm new to this.  I have setup a Ubuntu 12.04 server on a Dell PowerEdge FS-12.  I have setup a large area on the FS-12 (raid 50) to replace one of the drive mappings on the windows 2003 server.  I would like to change the mapping to access the new location I created on the Ubuntu server, but still continue using the Windows 2003 server Active Directory setup for the domain.

I have only installed Ubuntu 12.04 and formatted the new space.  I currently have it mounted /dev/sdb1 to /media/shared.  What do I need to install or setup to allow the windows clients to access the new space using the Windows2003 Server permission on the Domain?

Please help.

Thank you - Jeremy